# sql case when x=? then y=? end

Tags: sql, case, case-when

I ahve a problem with an sql case, I want to check a column value, and if that returns true then I want another column value to change, but in a 'case' you can only check one column and change only the value of that, how do I make it work?

```
select f.[film name],f.city,p.[participant name],
case rt.[type name]
when 'director' then 'director' else null
end 'role type'
from Films f 
join FilmParticipants fp on fp.filmID=f.filmID 
join Participants p on p.participantID=fp.participantID 
join RoleType rt on rt.roleID=fp.roleID
where f.city in(
select f.city
from Films f
group by f.city
having COUNT(*)>1)
order by f.city
```

it gives this table:

```
film name   | city       | participate name | role type
Shrek       | London     | John             | null
Shrek       | London     | John             | null
Dragon      | London     | Rick             | null
Drago       | London     | Morty            | Director
```

now I want that whenever there is null in the 'role type column' that the 'participate name' column will be null as well.

Comment: update you question add  a proper data sample and the expected result  and tell us which db you are using

Comment: what's your problem with the query ... ??

Comment: I have edited the post for a clearer understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use case when same way for role type and show partecipant.name

```
      select f.[film name],f.city,
       case rt.rt.[type name]
           when 'director' then p.[participant name] else null end 'partecipant',
      case rt.[type name]
           when 'director' then 'director' else null
      end 'role type'
      from Films f 
      join FilmParticipants fp on fp.filmID=f.filmID 
      join Participants p on p.participantID=fp.participantID 
      join RoleType rt on rt.roleID=fp.roleID
      where f.city in(
        select f.city
        from Films f
        group by f.city
        having COUNT(*)>1)

      order by f.city
```

for remove the null

```
      select [film name], city,  max(partecipant), max([role type])
      from (
      select f.[film name],f.city,
       case rt.rt.[type name]
           when 'director' then p.[participant name] else null end 'partecipant',
      case rt.[type name]
           when 'director' then 'director' else null
      end 'role type'
      from Films f 
      join FilmParticipants fp on fp.filmID=f.filmID 
      join Participants p on p.participantID=fp.participantID 
      join RoleType rt on rt.roleID=fp.roleID
      where f.city in(
        select f.city
        from Films f
        group by f.city
        having COUNT(*)>1)
      order by f.city ) t 
      group by [film name], city
```

Comment: thank you so much! this one was tricky.

    film name   | city       | participate name | role type
    Shrek       | London     | null            | null
    Dragon      | London     | null            | null
    Dragon       | London     | Morty            | Director

now it gives me this table, do you happen to know how do I make the 2nd row disappear? if that 'film name' already exist and it has those nulls, I dont need to see it.

Comment: it is accepted, I would appriciate of you helped me with my second problem though which ill post as a comment in a moment

Comment: answer  updated .. anyway  don't use answer  for question  .. is better if you remove you answer ... post a new question instead and eventually comment the link to your friends

Comment: ok, thanks, ill make a new question, btw the updated answer doesnt work because this 'having' you wrote deletes also row number one, it also has nulls but because it is the only one that shows this film name I need it